# Convert Image into base64binary in PHP

Tags: php, base64

Basically image/ document in **jpf / png / pdf** format needs to be converted into **base64Binary** and passed as json request.

Have seen a lot of code on the web but all are in Java or ASP. There is nothing I could find that would help with reading file and outputting base64binary value in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code. Assuming you can use `file_get_contents` function,

```
$file_type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$contents = file_get_contents($file_type);
$encoded = 'data:image/' . $file_type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($contents);
```

or you can use base64_encode function. Base64-encoded data takes about 33% more space than the original data.

```
$data = file_get_contents($contents);  
$encoded = base64_encode($data);  
echo $encoded;
```

Comment: This is one part of a huge request for API. Will know if this is working post getting the whole thing to work. In the API documentation shared with us, it was written as output needs to be in "base64binary ".. It's written as base64binary - File contents in byte array

Comment: I don't know about that. I haven't dealt with APIs